# Node js: says "no table exists" in browser but table does exist in terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku

I am new to Node JS here and I am trying to follow heroku's tutorial to provision a PostGres Database. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

This is how Im trying to display my data:

```
 pg.connect(procStr, function(err, client, done) {
      //console.log(client);

    client.query('SELECT * FROM table1', function(err, result) {
      done();
      if (err)
       { console.error(err); response.send("Error happened " + err); }
      else
       { response.render('/pages/db', {results: result.rows} ); }
    });
  });

});
```

I created the table exactly as described and in terminal everything is there:

[image]

But in browser I get `"Error happened error: relation "table1" does not exist"`

Only when I go to `/db` of course. What am I doing wrong?

CREATED TABLE:
   [image]

[image]

Comment: Is this happening in your development environment or on Heroku? Are you sure you're connecting to the right database in your JavaScript code? If this works in dev but not at Heroku, did you create the table at Heroku?

Comment: what do you mean dev? Im running this in terminal - i made the table using the commands in the question see edit-

Comment: "dev" would be the computer that you're developing on, I tagged it with heroku so I'd assume that you have two different environments. Also, your code is looking for `table1` but the "CREATED TABLE" you're showing is `test_table`.

Comment: yes I was showing that as the example. No I just have it on my computer, it is running via Heroku

Comment: Sorry but "I just have it on my computer, it is running via Heroku" doesn't make sense to me. Are you running this JavaScript on your computer but trying to connect to your database at Heroku? Is everything (your node.js app and database) at Heroku? Something else? Did you create the `table1` table at Heroku?

Comment: Sorry I'm new with this. I followed heroku's tutorial VERBATIM so in essence I believe I created everything via heroku. I did this via the terminal on my computer, but yes all in heroku.

Comment: If you `heroku pg:psql` and then do a `\dt`, is your table in the list?

Comment: Yes - see question I posted a picture.

Comment: Is your `procStr` set up to connect to the right database?

Comment: Yes, and Ive tried setting it to env.DATBASE_URL as well directly

Answer (score 0):

i think that you re not connected to the right database .Please verify that in your Heroku dashboard > datastores > database_name > View Cridentials

Comment: If I put in that url as a string I get other erros